# Migrating from Mysql to Cassandra Spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, cassandra

I am totally new to Cassandra, this is the very first time, never used it before, so far we have been using Spring Boot and MySql as our DB, but now we are planning to migrate our database to Cassandra with the minimum code or no change.
here is a sample demo of code that we have been using.

config class

```
package com.example.demo.config;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import lombok.Generated;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.HashMap;
import static org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings.*;
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "orclEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "orclTransactionManager", basePackages = {"com.example.demo.repository"})
@Generated
public class DataSourceConfig {
    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String orclDbDriver;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String orclDbConnUrl;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String orclDbUsername;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String orclDbPassword;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.poolName}")
    private String dataSourcePoolName;
    @Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect}")
    private String orclHibernateDialect;
    @Value("${spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto}")
    private String hibernateDDL;
    @Value("${spring.jpa.show-sql}")
    private boolean showSql;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.packagesToScan}")
    private String[] packagesToScan;
    public DataSourceConfig() {
    }
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource orclDataSource() {
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(this.orclDbDriver);
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(this.orclDbConnUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(this.orclDbUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(this.orclDbPassword);
        dataSource.setPoolName(this.dataSourcePoolName);
        return dataSource;
    }
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean orclEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(this.orclDataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan(this.packagesToScan);
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(Boolean.TRUE);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(showSql);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(orclHibernateDialect);
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap();
        properties.put(HBM2DDL_AUTO, this.hibernateDDL);
        properties.put(DIALECT, this.orclHibernateDialect);
        properties.put(STATEMENT_BATCH_SIZE, "500");
        properties.put(ORDER_UPDATES, "true");
        properties.put(ORDER_INSERTS, "true");
        properties.put(GENERATE_STATISTICS, "true");
        factory.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        return factory;
    }
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JpaTransactionManager orclTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(this.orclEntityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

controller class

```
import com.example.demo.entity.Child;
import com.example.demo.repository.ChildRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class HelloController {
    @Autowired
    private ChildRepository childRepository;

    @GetMapping("put")
    public Child getHello() {
        Child child = new Child();
        child.setName("shrikant");
        child.setUpdatedAt(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        return childRepository.save(child);
    }

    @GetMapping("get")
    public List<Child> hello() {
        return childRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

repository

```
package com.example.demo.repository;
import com.example.demo.entity.Child;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Repository
public interface ChildRepository extends JpaRepository<Child, Long> {
}
```

application.dev

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student_db?jdbcCompliantTruncation=false&sessionVariables=sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'&useSSL=false&useServerPrepStmts=false&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.poolName=springHikariCp
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.database.schema=student_db
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.packagesToScan=com.example.demo.entity
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '8'
configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'  
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok' 
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I have installed Cassandra with the help of google and able to login using `cqlsh`.

created keyspace

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS mykeyspace WITH replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':1};
```

added Cassandra dependency in Gradle

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra'
```

but what should be the configuration properties in the application.properties, I couldn't find any of the examples on Google creating a custom data source, all are using Spring Boot auto-config, but I can't do that, because that will be a major code change.

Comment: Unless your data model in the relational database is very specifically designed for a nosql database, you will not be able to just port across with no real code changes. I think the data model needs to be looked at first, because if that is designed in a normal relational manner, you already can determine that this will not be a 'minimal' change.

Comment: Adding to Andrew's point - everything in Cassandra starts with queries in mind - all tables are organized around the way you're getting data...

Comment: Spring Data Cassandra is fine for small projects.  But if you expect this to scale at some point, Spring Data Cassandra makes use of a few anti-patterns behind the scenes.  I always recommend folks use the DataStax Java Driver: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.8/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `CassandraRepository` instead of `JpaRepository` interface

```
public interface ChildRepository extends CassandraRepository<Child, Long> { }
```

You need to have these properties in your application.properties

```
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=127.0.0.1 (or your corresponding connection uri)
spring.data.cassandra.username=<username, if any>
spring.data.cassandra.password=<password, if any>
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace=default
spring.data.cassandra.port=9042
spring.data.cassandra.schema-action=NONE
```

Then you will be relatively fine. But like the other guys said in the comments section, it is quite important that you should understand the nature of Cassandra. If you don't implement your data model based on your queries, it won't be successful.

Comment: Can I use CrudRepository instead of CassandraRepository as one extends the other?